# uiprogressview ProgressTintColor in iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, backwards-compatibility, ios4, uiprogressview

I am trying to color a progress bar but mantaining compability with iOS 4.3. ProgresTintColor was introduced in iOS5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes... subclass `UIProgressView` and handle your own drawing.

Here's [a potentially useful how-to tutorial I found for you](http://goto11.net/skinning-a-uiprogressview-with-drawrect-and-images/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the class **PDColoredProgressview** available here: https://github.com/PascalW/PDColoredProgressview